How do I import my DataAccessLibrary into blazor project?
I am trying to import my data access library into my Program.cs file for a Blazor project, but my import is not working correctly.
Sharing a screenshot of my project structure:

Thank you in advance for any help!
I tried to import with using statement, but it does not work.

Did you add your DataAccessLibrary as a dependency to the Blazor project?
